# Need help loading shared library using Ctypes

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have to create a python wrapper for a large C library.  I am trying to use the ctypes module to do this however I am getting an error when I try to load the shared library.  Here is the python code I'm running at the moment.

```
import ctypes

praatlib_path = '/n/banquet/da/martega/Programming/libs/libpraat.so'
praatlib = ctypes.CDLL(praatlib_path)

print 'Hello, World!'
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error which I don't know enough to debug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./praatlib.py", line 9, in <module>
    praatlib = ctypes.CDLL(praatlib_path)
  File "/usr/local/lang/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /n/banquet/da/martega/Programming/libs/libpraat.so: undefined symbol: _Znaj
```

Can anyone explain what this means and how I can go about fixing it?

In case it's useful, here's the command in the Makefile that builds the shared library.

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libpraat.so -o libpraat.so `find num glpk audio stat LPC FFNet dwtools artsynth fon dwsys GSL kar FLAC mp3 library -name "*.o"`
```

**Edit:**  I recompiled it with g++ instead of C++.  This fixed the original error but now I'm getting the following error which is something I'll probably have to fix on my own:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./praatlib.py", line 9, in <module>
    praatlib = ctypes.CDLL(praatlib_path)
  File "/usr/local/lang/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /n/banquet/da/martega/Programming/libs/libpraat.so: undefined symbol: Melder_hasError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing symbol `_Znaj` demanges to `operator new[](unsigned int)`:

```
$ c++filt _Znaj
operator new[](unsigned int)
```

Try to compile your library using g++ instead of gcc

Comment: Thanks!  I'll recompile the library and the report back with my results.

Comment: How did you compile for libpraat.so